# plot large time stamp data on x axis in flot chart

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I want to plot a timeseries data from a date to another date at interval of 5 minutes.
In my flot chart the x axis labels are overlapping as the number of points are large,Is there any way to display such large number of data clearly on flot line chart. (like some x axis scrollable option) [image]

Comment: screenshot of type of char type

Comment: I have added the screenshot, x axis data is overlapped

Comment: Show some code (like your chart configuration).  The frequency of the ticks can be controlled by `minTickSize` (something like `minTickSize: [1, "month"]`, see docs here: https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Flot examples](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/) demonstrate a couple of ways to show a window onto a larger dataset.  You can use an [overview plot](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/visitors/index.html) or [control the window](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time/index.html) yourself.

While there isn't a built-in option for a scrollbar, you can use these to implement one.